# Instagram Graph API Access Token - Data Access - renew

Tags: api, cron, token, instagram

I just generated the Long Lived Access Token in order I could get "recent_media" for a hashtag.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{$hashtag_id}/recent_media?user_id={$user_id}&fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}
```

This works fine, but the Access Token (better say Data Access for this Token) expires in 3 months.

[image: Data Access Expiration]

I want to create a CRON job (running once per day), which will run the URL mentioned above (to get recent_media).

Will the Data Access be renewed automatically only thanks to this CRON job?

In the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing) there is:

> ... will automatically refresh tokens if the person has used your app...

But in my use case there is no person using my app. I used it manually in my browser only once to get the Token. And now there is only CRON job getting the recent media.

I probably need another CRON job for renewing the Token, but I dont know which API service I should use. The goal is having the Token renewed by the CRON job.

Thanks

Comment: I notice you've referenced the Facebook API documentation. Was that intentional? The docs for Long-Lived Access Tokens for the Instagram API are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens#refresh-a-long-lived-token). I'm also looking at using a cron job to automate token refresh. Will update here if I manage to get something working.

Comment: About the FB docs... it was a few months ago, so I'm not sure right now :-) But I think it was on purpose... because Instagram API isn't offering search by hashtag. Only FB API does...

Comment: ah ok - that makes sense.

Comment: @Petr did you find a way to renew the data access expiry? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: No, I didn’t :-/